# Why does SLSQP take such an unusual optimisation route?

Tags: optimization, openmdao

The gist for the script is available here:
https://gist.github.com/eufren/3f53eb285c7f426e678e1d63926fb34a

The total derivatives seem to be basically correct when I use `p.check_totals()` - typical relative difference is about 1e-5, with a maximum of 1e-2.

This is an animation of the optimisation process under SLSQP:
[image]

Instead of smoothly morphing from the start planform to the optimised planform (as I would expect for gradient-based optimisation), it snaps to the minimum allowed value for the chord, then takes an odd path of pulsing the wingspan while developing strange spikes along the wingspan. At the end it morphs smoothly into the final configuration as I would expect.

How can I diagnose the cause of this unusual optimisation? Is it caused by the initial design violating the constraints? Is it possible to tone down the step size SLSQP takes to prevent the immediate snap to the minimum bounds?

EDIT 1:
Following from Justin's reply, I made an animation of only the major iterations.

[image]

It appears marginally smoother, with less of the bouncing in wingspan.

Comment: I think SLSQP doesn't respect bounds during the iterations to final solution. I'd be curious to see what IPOPT does which does respect them. Really all these optimizers require hand tuning, and which parameter to tune is guesswork unless you're very familiar with the math behind it

Comment: SLSQP from scipy does respect bounds. SLSQP form pyoptsparse does not (its an older version of the fortran that didn't have that feature)

Answer (score 0):

The gist you provided isn't runnable, so its hard to give a definitive answer. We can see that your initial condition is pretty far off though just from the difference between the start and the optimal planform. That means that the gradients are likely to be pretty steep at your initial condition which will results in some large initial steps (the first few steps of an SQP method closely approximate gradient descent).

Thought your intuition is that it should smoothly approach the minimum, thats not really correct in general. Initial step sizes for quasi-newton methods are highly dependent on scaling and initial guesses. Also, you have to account for constraints and line search effects. All off that is also tied into the quasi-newton hessian approximation too. So the jerkiness you see is is a agglomeration of all of that.

one thing you could try would be to filter out line search steps and only look at "major iterations". Its harder than it sounds to filter out line searches, since the optimizer doesn't actually tell you which cases are line search vs which ones are major. A very good approximation of that is achieved by looking at the case recorder data from a driver, with the [`record_derivatives`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.9.2/features/recording/driver_options.html#driver-recording-options) option turned on. Any case that has a derivatives associated with it (not all will!) is a major iteration. Any one without it is a line search. If you make a opt-history-plot of just the major iterations it will look a lot more smooth.

Comment: Oops! Fixed the issue in the gist (was just an accidental tab in "fd"), it should run now. Updated the link in the original post.

Comment: The updated gist does run, but doesn't produce any optimization result. The solver fails to converge on its first iteration. I won't be able to offer any more advice without a working test case that gives expected behavior when I run it.

Comment: Odd, it works on my machine. Remove `from CoupledLiftingLineQuadraticDoublet import CoupledLLTQD` from SolarDrone, and run SolarDrone.py (not LiftingLine.py).